# Order of execution / priority of Hadoop map tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, priority-queue, hadoop-partitioning

I have ~5000 entries in my Hadoop input file, but I know in advance that some of the lines will take much longer to process than others (in the map stage).
(Mainly because I need to download a file from Amazon S3, and the size of the file will vary between tasks)

I want to make sure that the biggest map tasks are processed first, to make sure that all my hadoop nodes will finish working roughly at the same time.

Is there a way to do that with Hadoop? Or do I need to rework the whole thing? (I am new to Hadoop)

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, I don't think you can control the map load balancing (partitioning is between map and reduce phase). Every input split results in a map task. If it is possible you can try to manually group entries together (for example inside one file) such that a multiple entries are in the same split, but I don't know if that is possible for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you would implement your custom InputFormat (the getSplits() method contains the logic about split creation), then theoretically you could achieve what you want.

BUT, you have to take special care, because the order of how the InputFormat returns the splits is not the order of how Hadoop will process it.
There is a split re-ordering code inside the JobClient:

```
// sort the splits into order based on size, so that the biggest
// go first
Arrays.sort(array, new NewSplitComparator());
```

which will make the whole thing more tricky.
But you could implement a custom InputFormat + a custom InputSplit and make the InputSlip#length() dependent on its expected execution time.

Comment: Ok, I see the trick! However, wouldn't it be dangerous to have getLength() not returning the actual size? A quick search in the JobCLient shows that a lot of code is relying on this value to be correct

Comment: MMh its most important for the calculation of the job progress which is derived out of the splits length and the record-readers position. So if you implement the InputFormat you can pass out an own RecordReader implementation which handles the 'incorrect' size. So its all doable, but very hacky... welcome to Hadoop! ;)